# How to set the same document root for all server names on Apache

Tags: apache, config, document-root, server-name

I need a way to make all server names point to one document root without the need to manually type them all, maybe something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /www/example1
   ServerName *
</VirtualHost>
```

Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't write `ServerName *`.

All you have to do is put the DocumentRoot in the first virtual host that gets read in your configuration.  The Apache [Name-Based Virtual Hosts guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) explains that any server whose name doesn't match the ServerName in any virtual host configuration will be served by the default host, so it will get the DocumentRoot you want.